# Assume default value for global variable in Stylus stylesheet?

Tags: global-variables, stylus

One of the great things about [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) is that it allows you to define variables which can be used to customize the configuration of the resulting output.

For instance,

```
// my-html-object.styl

$my-html-object-color = red

$my-html-object
    color $my-html-object-color
```

But how would one define this variable so that it can be overridden before 'my-html-object.styl' is loaded such that the following is possible?

```
// main.styl

$my-html-object-color = blue

@import('my-html-object')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stylus offers two identical operators to achieve this `?=` and `:=` as documented here:

http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/operators.html#conditional-assignment--

For completeness here is an example showing the two alternative (but equivalent) syntaxes:

**Example 1:**

```
// my-html-object.styl

$my-html-object-color ?= blue

$my-html-object
    color $my-html-object-color
```

**Example 2:**

```
// my-html-object.styl

$my-html-object-color := blue

$my-html-object
    color $my-html-object-color
```

And then in both cases you can adjust the value as intended:

```
// main.styl

$my-html-object-color = blue

@import('my-html-object')
```